# How can I mock instantiation of an object using static inner class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have the below method that I need to unit test.

How can I mock creation of the `LDUser` object below?

```
public void isFeatureFlagOn(String featureFlagId, TransactionContext transContext, boolean defaultReturnState)
    throws TAServiceException {
        boolean returnState = defaultReturnState;
        try {
            LDUser ldUser = new LDUser.Builder(transContext.getAuthId()).build();
            returnState = ldClient.boolVariation(featureFlagId, ldUser, defaultReturnState);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            returnState = defaultReturnState;
        }

        if (!returnState) {
            throw new TAServiceException("This service is not available", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is [my article here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) of any use?

Answer (score 0):

It's really not feasible unless you use something like PowerMock for this. However, you may want to consider injecting the `LDUser` builder so that you can mock the builder when you call your method under test. With the builder mock, you can mock how it builds the mock `LDUser` instance you want. So, your test method would look something like:

```
// ...
when(mockLdUserBuilder.build()).thenReturn(mockLdUser);
classUnderTest.methodUnderTest(mockLdUserBuilder);
// ... assert/verify stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `package` level method that you can use to inject a mocked builder.

```
 public void isFeatureFlagOn(...) throws TAServiceException {
     boolean returnState = defaultReturnState;
     try {
        getBuilder(transContext.getAuthId()).build();
        ...
     }
   ...
 }
 //package method
 Builder getBuilder(int authId) {
     return new LDUser.Builder(authId);
 }
```

And then in your test you can override this method.

```
@Mock
LDUser.Builder builder; 

@Test
public void test1() {
  MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {
    @Override
    Builder getBuilder(int authId) {
      return builder;
    }
  }
  myClass.isFeatureFlagOn(...);
  ...
}
```